# Android better way to do button clicks?

Tags: android, button, click

So right now I'm tidying up some code, and I have a lot of else/ifs for buttons and was wondering what is a good way to do it and make it neater?

So I have like 12 buttons, and each button plays a sound and changes colour when clicked. I have a method for this but I was wondering is there a good way to just detect the button instead of if/else?

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    changeToWhite();
    if (id == R.id.a_button) {
        currentButton(a, 81);
    } else if (id == R.id.aSharp_button) {
        currentButton(aSharp, 82);
    } else if (id == R.id.b_button) {
        currentButton(b, 83);
    } else if (id == R.id.c_button) {
        currentButton(c, 72);
    }
```

Etc...

So is there a better way of having this? I know having a lot of else/ifs is bad so I wanted to try improve it.
Thanks!!

Comment: For starters, you could use a `switch` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "switch-case" instead.

>

```
public void onClick(View v) {
switch(v.getId())
{
case R.id.a_button:
changeToWhite();
break;
case R.id.aSharp_button:
currentButton(aSharp,82);
break;
.....
default:
break;
}
```

}

Comment: You can use switch-case? Somebody told me it doesn't work in Android! If it works that

Comment: Dang hit enter too quick.Thanks!

Comment: @AndyOHart - switch cases won't work if your R.id were generated in a library project (where they are non-final), but using your own R.id's will work just fine in a switch statement

Answer (score 1):

How about using a case statement instead?

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
       // Perform action on click
      switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.a_button:
          currentButton(a, 81);
          break;
        case R.id.aSharp_button:
          currentButton(aSharp, 82);
          break;
        /*
          and the rest of the cases here.
        */

      }
   }
```

Comment: You can use case statements? I was told you can't do them in Android! If that works then great :) Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You can't use swicth/case only when your project is library project.

Comment: @Bruno Mateus What does that mean exactly?

Comment: As @ianhanniballake has explained better before. "switch cases won't work if your R.id were generated in a library project (where they are non-final), but using your own R.id's will work just fine in a switch statement"

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using XML and setting the onClick property.

An easier/tidier way is to use [anonymous inner classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html).

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_foo);

    findViewById(R.id.view_buttonone).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            // button one clicked
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.view_buttontwo).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            // button two clicked
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is **virtually no penalty** for using if/else nesting. There's no need to try this level of micromanaging your app. You will gain no benefits from it. Try to think more of optimizing this point in terms of readability.

Now, to answer your question, you could use a switch/case construct instead.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.aBar_item1:
         //Item onClick logic
         return true;

        case R.id.aBar_item2:
        //Item onClick logic
        return true;

        case R.id.aBar_item3:
        //Item onClick logic
        return true;

        ...
    }  
}
```

Comment: The only reason I wanted to change it was because it is for college and they said if they saw a lot of if/else statements we would probably be very penalised. But for stuff like this where it picks up a button click I'm not sure if there is a better way